# How many players to fill a channel

Tags: blade-and-soul

Say Cerulean Order faction members are grouping to take on Blackwrym but do not want Crimson Legion players to enter the channel and disrupt the boss fight. Is there any information anywhere that says how many people it would take to not let anyone new join that particular channel (regardless of faction)? I am aware that using a party invite bypasses the channel max-cap.